# Using a series of Text objects in an array

Tags: modifiers, text-object

I've been trying to use an of array text objects for equidistant placement around an empty, but I could never accomplish this.  Is there a way as shown in this photo (the speedometer numbers).  I know that the values are different and an array would have the same text values.
[image: Speedometer text values]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Clamp To` Constraint on a `Bezier Circle` to get this, you have to do each separate piece of text, but you can use the same curve. Like this:
[image]

To rotate the text move along whatever axis (in my case it was the *Y*). To rotate a certain number of degrees you can use this formula: `(r/90) * degrees`. So if you want to turn *90 degrees* and you have a radius of *3* then just move the same distance as the radius. Also check `Cyclic` if you want the text to be able to go more than a full circle.
To continue just do this:
[image]

To figure out how far to move the text each time I used that equation. For me it was: `(1.5 / 90) * 270 (3/4 of a circle)` This gives `4.5`, then you want to split that distance between *10* items, so you get to move it `0.45` on the `-X` axis in my case.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, awesome!